# Control precision of CPU or MEM percentage in top?

Tags: arch-linux, top

Looks like the default precision has changed in Arch, but I checked `top (1)`, I didn't find anything related to `precision`, maybe I've used the wrong jargon.

[image]

Right now it's 3 bit precision, I want only one. How can I change that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking of the `top` from [procps-ng](http://gitorious.org/procps), then it's done at compilation time.

Wide percentages used to be off by default, and you had to change it (`PERCENTBOOST` in `top/top.h`), but now it's on by default (see [this change](http://gitorious.org/procps/procps/commit/21e550bc080eb30f503b2ca6fe4e9cb12b8a1616)), and you turn it off with `NOBOOST_MEMS` and `NOBOOST_PCNT` in `top/top.h`.

You could do:

```
sudo perl -pi-orig -e 's/%#\.3f/%#.1f/g;s/%#\.2f/%#.0f/g' "$(
  command -v top)"
```

But that wouldn't reclaim the screen real-estate.

Or you could use other `top` implementations like `htop`.